# PHP Show XML coordinates on Google Maps

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, maps

I have a page in my CodeIgniter project that shows a google maps api, and I want it to show coordinates from an XML file I created at the root of my project.  I've tested it with a .xml file provided from a server on a tutorial I followed and it worked. I'm trying to make it work with my own XML file but it seems like the file can't be found. Here is the code for the function that makes the coordinates appear on the map:

```
function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.837049838196, -71.094652204138),
        zoom: 12
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

   // this is the URL that should be pointing to an XML file I have stored at the root of my CodeIgniter project.

    downloadUrl('http://127.0.0.1/BD3_TP1/xml/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
            var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
            var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
            var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
            var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
            var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
            var strong = document.createElement('strong');
            //   strong.textContent = name
            infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

            var text = document.createElement('text');
            text.textContent = address
            infowincontent.appendChild(text);
            var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I even copied the tutorial xml file's content and replicated it. When I put the original URL(https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml) in the downloadUrl function seen previously, it works. The error is the URL I wrote, which points to my stored xml file. It won't find the file, so the coordinates don't appear. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I created the xml file  with the PHPstorm IDE. As it turns out, when I checked in the file folder itself with the file explorer, the xml file was just a blank file. I opened it with notepad and saved it as xml and my code worked. Don't trust PHPstorm with creating XML files.